# How to deploy Flask wsgi application on OPENSHIFT

Tags: python, deployment, flask, openshift, wsgi

I have flask app that work perfect on vps with using mod_wsgi. On vps server  I configure virtual-host.

I clone my project from  github and create wsgi file in repo dir.
wsgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os

base_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, base_dir)


def application(environ, start_response):
    from server import app as application
    return application(environ, start_response)
```

I have next project structure:

```
server.py
wsgi
--app(folder)
--template(folder)
--static(folder)
--etc(folder)
--bin(folder)
```

when I curl my site or open pages in browser I got 404 response code and text "error"

in openshift logs/python.log I have only messages with 404 code

How to resolve this or how to deploy flask wsgi app correct.

Comment: OpenShift Python cartridge expects the WSGI script file to be called 'wsgi.py', not just 'wsgi'.

Comment: resolved with adding wsgi folder with wsgi file in it.

Comment: From memory, if you are using a ``wsgi`` directory, the file in it would need to be called ``application``. This is an older way that OpenShift supported setting it up, but using a ``wsgi.py`` file in the top level directory is now the preferred way.

Comment: thanks. I resolved this issue with using /wsgi/application file.
I know about wsgi.py but it doesn't work. Also i try to set env variable to different path to wsgi.py file. In this way application is running but always return 404 response code with text "error".
Now my application is running but i have some troubles with mysql db connection. I am using tcp socket and i have connection to mysq DB from python code but I cant get any data

Answer (score 1):

There is one of my Recent Questions on [Deploying Flask in OPENSHIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051871/deploying-flask-in-openshift)

There is not much of help, as noon has given any anwser YET..
But anyway, hope the directory tree and wsgi.py file sample would be of some help..

```
myflaskaws
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── static
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── style.css
│   │   └── images
│   │       ├── no.png
│   │       └── yes.png
│   ├── templates
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── login.html
│   ├── searchlist.html
│   ├── update.html
├── test.py
├── test.pyc
└── wsgi.py`
```

wsgi.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
virtenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'] + '/virtenv/'
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass

from test import app as application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    httpd = make_server('localhost', 8051, application)
    print("Serving at http://localhost:8051/ \n PRESS CTRL+C to Terminate. \n")
    httpd.serve_forever()
    print("Terminated!!")
```