# Deploying Flask in Openshift

Tags: python, flask, openshift, pymongo, wsgi

The following codes are working without any problem in my system's localhost... But ain't doing the job on OpenShift..
There is something wrong with my **wsgi.py**..  Do I have to pass my username and password using environment variables OR I've need to change the *localhost* ?

The following is the tree of the directory/repository...

```
myflaskaws
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── static
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── style.css
│   └── images
│       ├── no.png
│       └── yes.png
├── templates
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── login.html
│   ├── searchlist.html
│   ├── update.html
├── test.py
├── test.pyc
└── wsgi.py`
```

---

**wsgi.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
virtenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'] + '/virtenv/'
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass
from test import app as application
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    httpd = make_server('localhost', 8051, application)
    print("Serving at http://localhost:8051/ \n PRESS CTRL+C to Terminate. \n")
    httpd.serve_forever()
    print("Terminated!!")
```

---

**test.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

PS : I'm not using "*if **name** == '**main**':*" in **test.py**

Comment: Explain how it is not working, what error you are seeing and where. If ``myflaskaws`` is a sub directory of your repo, that will not work. OpenShift 2 expects everything in that directory to be at the root of the repo. Also, for OpenShift 2, the static files need to be in a directory ``wsgi/static`` and not ``static`` relative to repo root.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton : myflaskaws is the APP-NAME.. You mean I need to move static to  wsgi ( New Folder ?)... What else has to be in the wsgi folder?

Comment: You haven't explained yet how it is not working. Where do you see an error, the browser or the logs? What is the error? Or is the issue only that css and other statics is not working? As to ``static`` location, what you want is ``mkdir wsgi; mv static wsgi/``. Please try and explain what the issue is first.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton error saying "500 internal server error"...  It was working fine on my system...

Comment: If you are seeing a generic 500 error from Apache and nothing in the errors logged by Apache (you have looked?), then it would be your Flask application code which is failing. Try temporarily enabling Flask debug so that details of the error appear in your browser, or set up Flask to properly log details of its errors to  standard error so capture in the Apache error log file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to use Openshift's environment variables to set up the IP and port.

Try adding in the below code to setup the proper IP and port depending if you are on OS or localhost.

```
Import os

if 'OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME' in os.environ:              #are we on OPENSHIFT?
    ip = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP']
    port = int(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT'])
else:
    ip = '0.0.0.0'                            #localhost
    port = 8051

httpd = make_server(ip, port, application)
```

Comment: The port is only relevant if not using the builtin Apache/mod_wsgi and you are supply your own runnable web server/application in an ``app.py`` file. They are not supplying an ``app.py`` file but have a ``wsgi.py`` file which is what Apache/mod_wsgi would use. The issue may be where it is located, but since not explanation of error yet, hard to tell.